# Jenkins post JUnit report on github pull request

Tags: github, jenkins, junit, continuous-integration

I've already made `Jenkins` test the `pull request` and post the result( success or fail ) like this.

[image]

Developers can click the Details button, and it will open `jenkin's` page to display the error messages.

However, I want to directly display the error message on the github instead of check on the jenkin's page.

Is there any way to achieve that?

If I need to tell more information, please let me know.

### Update

I add `Github PR post comment` in **Post build task** like this. The column of `Content` is default, I'm not sure it's correct or not.

[image]

But I didn't see the comment after the `jenkins` retest,  did I set the configuration wrongly?

Comment: I don't think you can show your results in this build-result-box, however you could let jenkins write a comment on the pull-request to give additional information.

Comment: @tkausl I update my question, please check it.

Comment: @CodaChang can you tell me how you achieve that ?

Comment: @hemal7735 What do u have now? Can you see Jenkins's test result now?

Comment: @CodaChang I was able to see the test summary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I choose to post error message directly at comment via `python` and [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/)

And I used this script https://gist.github.com/rmcgibbo/3433798, it's really useful.

Comment: How to Use the script mentioned in Jenkins.?